# How to convert Pandas DataFrame into Pandas ML ModelFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I would like to repeat these [example_1](http://pandas-ml.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modelframe.html) [example_2](http://pandas-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xgboost.html) with my dataset.

```
import pandas_ml as pdml

df = pdml.ModelFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2, 3, 4],
                   'C': [3, 4, 5]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df
   A  B  C
a  1  2  3
b  2  3  4
c  3  4  5
```

But, the issue is I have my data set in a csv file.

```
x_test = pd.read_csv("x_test.csv",sep=';',header=None)
```

I've tried to convert pandas data frame to dict, but it didn't work.

So, the question is there a way for converting the pandas dataframe into Pandas-Ml ModelFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `orient`:

```
x_test = pd.read_csv("x_test.csv",sep=';',header=None)
df = pdml.ModelFrame(x_test.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

Comment: Glad can help you!